# Graph using mpAndroid Chart xAxis is not displaying the date i formatted

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I have a code to display a data in a line graph and I need to change the **xAxis** to date but the log have a error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2019-04-19 00:00:00"
```

Below is my code snippet for line graph

```
mLineChart = findViewById(R.id.chart)

    importData()

    val dataSet = LineDataSet(entries, "Water")
    val lineData = LineData(dataSet)
    mLineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
    mLineChart.data = lineData
    dataSet.color = Color.RED
    dataSet.setDrawCircles(false)
    dataSet.setDrawValues(false)
    dataSet.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
    mLineChart.description.text = ""
    mLineChart.legend.isEnabled = false
    mLineChart.invalidate()


    val leftAxis = mLineChart.axisLeft
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART)
    leftAxis.axisMinimum = 0f
    leftAxis.axisMaximum = 30f


    val rightAxis = mLineChart.axisRight
    rightAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART)
    rightAxis.axisMinimum = 0f
    rightAxis.axisMaximum = 30f

    var xAxis = mLineChart.xAxis
    xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
    xAxis.axisMinimum = 0f
    xAxis.labelCount = 5
    xAxis.axisMaximum = 400f
    xAxis.granularity = 1f
    xAxis.isGranularityEnabled = true
    xAxis.valueFormatter = DateAxisValueFormatter(null)
```

Below is my code snippet for inserting data

```
private fun importData() {

                for (data in dataList) {
                    val date = java.lang.Float.parseFloat(data.date)
                    val water = java.lang.Float.parseFloat(data.water)

                    entries.add(Entry(date, water))
                }
```

Below is my code snippet for value formatter

```
    internal inner class DateAxisValueFormatter(private val mValues: Array<String>?) : ValueFormatter(),
    IAxisValueFormatter {

    var sdf = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)

    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
        return sdf.format(Date(value.toLong()))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is clear, you're trying to convert a string into Float, but this string is not a Number.

If you want to display a date, you have to format your date in milliseconds before.
Try something like that:

```
private fun importData() {
val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)

                for (data in dataList) {
                    val date = dateFormatter.parse(data.date)
                    val water = java.lang.Float.parseFloat(data.water)

               //Here you get your date as a Long and you convert it in Float
                    entries.add(Entry(date.time.toFloat(), water))
                }
```

EDIT:
In your xAxis set your own valueFormatter this way to convert your float back in date:

```
  val x = chart.xAxis
    x.setValueFormatter { value, _ ->
        SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(value.toLong())
    }
```

Comment: when i do this my xAsis become "1.55560326E12 " but i need it bo be like this  "HH:mm" format

Comment: @ArnolfoTeope I edited my answer to give you an example on how to get your date back in a readable value

Comment: when i use this code " xAxis.valueFormatter = IAxisValueFormatter { value, _-> SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH).format(value.toLong()) } as ValueFormatter " as my formatter the application gave me an error " formatter$1 cannot be cast to com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.ValueFormatter "

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast it, it should already be the same type. If you encounter an issue check your imported packages and make sure to use this one "import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter"

Comment: when i did not cast it it and do this "xAxis.valueFormatter = IAxisValueFormatter { value, _-> SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(value.toLong()) }" it shown me a error of "Type mismatch.
Required:
ValueFormatter!
Found:
IAxisValueFormatter"

Comment: That's weird, you may need to update your version of AndroidMPChart, make sure you're using the version 3.0 or higher. Also check [this guide](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-AxisValueFormatter-interface) to understand how to set your custom AxisValueFormatter, hope this helps